# Follow the Path, but is it valid?

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, decision-problem, path-finding

## Follow the Path

I got directions to my friend's house, but it looks like his map might have some mistakes. He's expecting me soon, so I need some short code to figure out if I can get there.

## The Challenge

The code should, when given an ASCII representation of a path as input, traverse from the start to the end, and output depending on whether there is a valid path.

## Input

Input is an ASCII representation of a map. It will use only the following symbols:

```
Character = Meaning
(space) = Blocked area
| = Vertical Path
- = Horizontal Path
+ = Intersection
^ or v = Horizontal Bridge
< or > = Vertical Bridge
$ = Start Location
# = End Location
```

## Traversal Rules

- Execution always starts on `$` and will end when all paths are blocked, an infinite loop, or the pointer hits `#`. It is guaranteed that input will have exactly 1 of each.
- The pointer starts moving to the right and down.
- Vertical paths will only connect to vertical paths, vertical bridges, or intersections.
- Horizontal paths will only connect to horizontal paths, horizontal bridges, or intersections.
- If a vertical and horizontal path meet at a non-bridge, it is considered blocked at that point.
- Bridges function according to the following:

```
 |      |
-^- OR -v- = Horizontal path going over a vertical path
 |      |

 |      |
-<- OR ->- = Vertical path going over a horizontal path
 |      |
```

- When the pointer hits an intersection, movement precedence is in the clockwise direction (up, right, down, left). The pointer will not go back the way it came.
- The program must detect/calculate infinite loops and branching paths from `+`.

## Output

The length of the path, or `-1`, according to the following conditions:

- If the program reaches `#`, output the path length.
- If the program detects only blocked paths, return `-1`.
- If the program detects an infinite loop, return `-1`.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins! [Standard loopholes are forbidden.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

## Test Cases

```
   $
   | 
 +-|
#+-+
= 6 (going north at `#+-` will lead to a blocked path, but going to the west is a valid path)

#-+-+
  | |
$-^-+
  +-+
= -1 (Will infinitely loop)

$#
= 1

#^^^^+
     >
$----^-+
     > +
     +-+
= 20

$------+
|-----+|
 --#--+|
+--+---+
+------+
= 23

$ #
= -1 (Blocked by the space)

$|#
= -1 (Can't go onto a vertical path from the sides)

$
-
#
= -1 (Can't go onto a horizontal path from the top or bottom)

$|#
|--|
++++
= -1 (No valid paths exist)
```

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman If you go north, you will eventually hit a blocked path, meaning that path is invalid. However, this is also a valid path to the west, which is where the 4 should be a 6. I'll add in clarification.

Comment: I see, so you automatically look ahead to see that a turn will be invalid if you would be blocked, but not if there is a loop? I'd highlight that some more since it is fine, but surprising.

Comment: I've put in some more clarification

Comment: Shouldn't the fourth test case result in `20` instead of `19`? You first go underneath the bridge at the intersection, and after that a second time across it. So `5 (east) + 4 (south) + 2 (east) + 2 (north) + 7 (west) = 20`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yeah, that should be 20.

Comment: @Arnauld Aight, will remove.

Comment: "Execution always starts on $ and will end when all paths are blocked, an infinite loop, or the pointer hits #." <-- Detecting an infinite loop for a small input is possibly trivial, but it's impossible to determine if the code will go into an infinite loop *somewhere* may require solving the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). It may still be (somewhat) possible to detect any infinite loop for any input, but I believe the question would be a lot more accessible if infinite loops weren't allowed.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 219 bytes

Takes input as a list of lists of characters.

```javascript
a=>((g=(X,Y,D,n=o=0)=>!(a+0)[n++]|a.some((r,y)=>r.some((c,x)=>D=='975'[i='-| #+$'.indexOf(c),x-X+1]-'450'[y-Y+1]?i-3?i-2?i>3?[3,0,7,4].some(d=>D^d^4&&g(x,y,d,n)):~i&&i^D&1?0:g(x,y,D,n):0:o=-n:X+1|i<5?0:g(x,y,2))))(),~o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFfa4MwFMXf@ykyFU1Irth/lMmiL33fa4soiNqS0SWjHcNC6Fd3aTtKdGwe8OGce/O7ufGt/CpP1VF8fIJUddPteFfyBOM9xxu2ZWsmueIR4ckTLmlEMklprsvwpN4bjI/sbCrHH1ex1rg158HzahlkggegkUu9IBSybtrXHa4Ia2FDpzkEi2UUZGfYGpMKmJtvlopknmZzFrEVW@R3aG2ARV0sfH@PW3ZmNZOExBfh@6JY@9M0iu@5uSeJo1hxkLEZoMXL8lGbESNM2EWRrlLypA5NeFB7vMPZBKEsDEMHIeQ5ObOsti0F27oUqJNPckImf@BcuLVYPN0DelAM6qNIzx0ZWRhRQ@ptgVDSizwwGs6@dqFf0fiN4Cb7oL4nvbcDcAcRNX5wkD5Y/05EI4/g6bEGaybYv3Sci3pr9vYxuloD6L4B)

#### How?

Because they need to be tried in a specific order, the way the directions are handled in this code is a bit unusual.

Given a direction \$D\$ and the source coordinates \$(X,Y)\$, we want to figure out which target coordinates \$(x,y)\$ correspond to a move by one square along \$D\$.

We use the following test for each candidate pair \$(x,y)\$:

```javascript
D == '975'[x - X + 1] - '450'[y - Y + 1]
```

This test always fails if \$|x-X|>1\$ or \$|y-Y|>1\$ because we get an undefined value from at least one of the 2 lookup strings.

Otherwise, we have the following table:

$$\begin{array}{r|c|ccc}
&x-X&-1&0&+1\\
\hline
y-Y&&9&7&5\\
\hline
-1&-4&5&3&1\\
0&-5&4&2&0\\
+1&-0&9&7&5
\end{array}$$

Because diagonal moves are not used, our final compass looks as follows:

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
&&3\\
&&↑\\
4&←&2&→&0\\
&&↓\\
&&7
\end{array}$$

The lookup values were chosen in such a way that we end up with some handy properties:

- Opposite directions can be detected by testing if \$d\operatorname{xor}d'=4\$. Hence the code to try all directions in clockwise order except the one that would make us going back the way we came:

  ```javascript
    [3, 0, 7, 4].some(d => D ^ d ^ 4 && g(x, y, d, n))
  ```
- Vertical moves are connected to odd values.
- Horizontal moves are connected to even values (except direction \$2\$, for no move at all, which is only used at the beginning of the process when the starting point has been identified).

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 934 bytes:

```py
E=enumerate
V=lambda b,X,Y:0<=X<len(b)and 0<=Y<len(b[0])and b[X][Y]!=' '
def U(D,x,X):D[x]=D.get(x,[])+[X];D[X]=D.get(X,[])+[x]
def f(b):
 m,W=[[0,1,'-^'],[1,0,'|>'],[0,-1,'-^'],[-1,0,'|>']],{'^':'-','>':'|'}
 x,y=[[x,y]for x,r in E(b)for y,t in E(r)if'$'==t][0]
 q,D=[(x,y,0,not V(b,x,y+1))],{}
 while q:
  x,y,p,l=q.pop(0)
  if'#'==b[x][y]:return p
  if b[x][y]in'>^':
   for j,k,I in[(X,Y,i)for i,(X,Y,u)in E(m)if b[x][y]in u]+[(m[l][0],m[l][1],l)]:
    if(x+j,y+k)not in D.get((x,y),[])and(b[x+j][y+k]in'>#^+'or b[x+j][y+k]==W[b[x][y]]):U(D,(x,y),(x+j,y+k));q+=[(x+j,y+k,p+1,I)];break       
  elif'+'==b[x][y]:
   T,O=[0,1,2,3],[]
   for i in T[l:]+T[:l]:
    if V(b,X:=x+m[i][0],Y:=y+m[i][1])and(X,Y)not in D.get((x,y),[]):
     if'#'==b[X][Y]:return p+1
     O+=[((X,Y),i)]
   if O:U(D,(x,y),O[0][0]);q+=[(*O[0][0],p+1,O[0][1])]
  elif V(b,X:=x+m[l][0],Y:=y+m[l][1])and b[X][Y]in(m[l][2]+'#+'):U(D,(x,y),(X,Y));q+=[(X,Y,p+1,l)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNNc9owED3Xv0KNmZEVrTMY8ulEnMghl3JJExhVdPBgGgdjjDFTmLq/PV1JxqUzrg6S9mm1@96ulB/Kt3XWv82Lj49HEWe7VVzMyth5EelsFc1nJIIxTMLugxg/pHHmRWyWzQmaE2vKrjJIJMdKTtRnQQl15vGCfPWGsIcxC4dyr8Tw4kdcenuQinH0vB/iVINjC@6VubbADKFDVvAqpOxCANSfUgUygC7QaqC3XfAb2G9wBb/olIbUp0AHuFb0t0P2cMAwOKvFukCrIElGHjGFNg9QWrNgyYJ2qBClQjkO2cBQSCR7wNjZuiQvXoRSDjxgDLNg2J9vSRqTDfLUGSCHVGwu8nXudRlCGMzFYBFKkgcVFnG5KzKSmxNSo0lGB8gWMaKpvMMSnpCMxGpMIDH0EjDGjhmOK3Z6mewUl95KppowmDVQkDJlImIeb8/fkfGSaf7ob0utNTFdbuwYtg59MBxfGjbulFPMeoIK8SrrjIqFup/2fhOb3W@4LpQ1IecBPDF1HxXxbEnsQDpxigXhJwXRFJ9hJEx7e9DHNqpjIRJN9lmmoeLPMkwbPaYH41Ds@UomRvQkFAdrBFYPFus/am2Qv30xL7XpCw/s8UhrMVGwAYYQph2d6B5hWv3crerz2jSyzR55qFrvKd30lG56pHv8MElm29hTnLqc/lNnzaXOpl@CToQt/tDfpFx/j9azYu7NUd2nWoqU54lqqrhI0jIuvC/rLAYyv9jmaVJ69FtG8RU7zjYggpydnWmdHT1V2CvuV47Lfe7og21P6MX1NaDPK6fjT82@celrl46r98720vpPcXDTeRwD/QY6Pg5700D1polyZS4aLx@xyq6VQ3zfNRuOszniRx9z79pK6BBDYHtTm5U1b21Ux3esfWftytUJMCYOEyYvkqz0Fl5T0i3@c9YC99rhfjt82Q5ftcPX7fBNO3zbDt8h/PEH)